# Google geolocation api quest

Tags: google-geolocation

I sent the base station information of location A to the Google geolocation api, but it returned the latitude and longitude values ​​of location B. In this case, can you tell me how to request re-modification to the Google geolocation DB or how to request if the base station information is incorrect?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) that demonstrates the issue. A sample request would be good.